# How to check explore_lite exited

Tags: ros-noetic

There is no exit information in `/explore/frontiers` topic.
How do I know if [explore_lite](http://wiki.ros.org/explore_lite) has exited?

Comment: Do you want to see in rviz that this `stop()` https://github.com/hrnr/m-explore/blob/noetic-devel/explore/src/explore.cpp#L288-L293 has been called?  You could modify that source code to publish a marker of your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hrnr/m-explore/blob/noetic-devel/explore/src/explore.cpp#L288-L293
I modified the function in the link above (I added my own publisher to the `Explore::stop` function) and rebuilt it.